# Swift UI List: Open external URL when cell is tapped

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to open a `URL` when one of the `List`'s cells is tapped. I tried adding the modifier `onTapGesture` to the cell itself and then calling `UIApplication.shared.open(url)`, but this only works if the tap is right on the cell view's elements (and not on the cell's background).

I also tried to add a background view (Rectangle) to the cell with opacity 0.01, but although this works the Rectangle is quite visible despite its low opacity.

Is there any workaround to make the whole row tappable?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, here it is in case it helps anyone in the future:

// edit:

Used a single `Button`, with the required action (i.e. `openURL` in my case) in the action closure, and with my custom view returned in the `label` closure.

Answer (score 0):

@stakri, What you're looking for is ".contentShape()"

```swift
Rectangle()
    .stroke()
    .onTapGesture() {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!)
    }
```

above code will only work if you tap on the 'stroke' outline of the rectangle, but .contentShape() will make the entire area tappable without the need to nest it inside of a Stack:

```swift
Rectangle()
    .stroke()
    .contentShape( Rectangle() )
    .onTapGesture() {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!)
    }
```

Others coming to this question will likely be looking for how to specifically open a URL, you'll notice I force unwrapped my URL. Open to feedback on that, but barring any issues brought up, this works well.

Comment: This is indeed a good solution if someone wants to use `onTapGesture`. I would still go with the single `Button` acting as a container since then I don't need to specify the tappable shape at all. Will upvote but still keep question open because I think both solutions are interesting.